# Part of footer is getting hidden

Tags: css

I am working on a developing a site for my company.  I am stuck on one issue where the layout is not working correctly.  The footer at the bottom is partially being covered.  I have added a z-index and it changed nothing.  I have played with margins and paddings to no avail.  Hopefully someone can see what is causing it to be partially covered.
Here is an image showing what I see:
[image]

And the website is here: http://clubschoicemagic.com/

```css
#slide03.slide .footer-container {
  background-color: #06060d;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#slide03.slide .footer-container .wrapper {
  background-color: #06060d;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto -20px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: none;
  top: auto;
  transform: none;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-container">
  <footer class="wrapper">
    <img src="http://clubschoicefundraising.com/Content/img/logo.png" class="center-block" width="80" />
    <h3>
                    Clubschoicemagic.com is affiliated with <a href="http://clubschoicefundraising.com">Club's Choice Fundraising</a>.
                </h3>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually nothing to do with your CSS as @Bart helped me notice.

at around line 200 (of your HTML) you have this;

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".contactForm").on('submit', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var firstName = $("#firstName").val();
                if (firstName == "") {
                    firstName = "None given";
                }
                var model = { firstName: firstName, schoolName: $("#schoolName").val(), note: $("#note").val() };

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/Index",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { model: model },
                    success: function (result) {
                        if (result) {
                            $(".contactForm").trigger('reset');
                            $("#formMessage").html("Thank you.  Your entry has been submitted.");
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

                    }
                });

            });
        });
    </script>
>
```

as you can see after the close script tag there is a stray `>` that is the cause of your problems.

Also `margin: 0 auto -20px;` should be `margin: 0 auto;` as @Tezekiel said

Comment: Thanks for the help in spotting that!

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this

```
margin: 0 auto -20px;
```

from your footer CSS.

Comment: There's also a stray '>' character at the bottom of the page, obscuring part of the footer.

Comment: removing that line, pushes it up, but I want it to stay in place and just remove that gray bar at the bottom.

Comment: @dmikester1 I examined it even more closely and found it ;-)

Comment: Hah!  You guys were right!  Found that elusive '>', removed it, and VOILÀ it works!